# Android adding image to view programatically getting this error java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB

Tags: android, imageview

Getting below error while adding an image to view dynamically.
Note: I am using .svg to set an image.

```
  java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
        at libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry.registerNativeAllocation(NativeAllocationRegistry.java:219)
        at libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry.registerNativeAllocation(NativeAllocationRegistry.java:122)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.<init>(Bitmap.java:137)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:1026)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:980)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:930)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:891)
        at com.rpoli.localwire.libs.circleimageview.CircularImageView.a(CircularImageView.java:411)
        at com.rpoli.localwire.libs.circleimageview.CircularImageView.a(CircularImageView.java:401)
        at com.rpoli.localwire.libs.circleimageview.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:337)
  at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:281)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:450)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(Drawable.java:229)
```

Comment: are you using any image loading library for image loading like Glide, Picasso etc.

Comment: @deepakkumar i am using picasso

Comment: please share the code too in which you are loading the image dynamically

Comment: [ public static void showCircularPic(Context ctx, String path, CircularImageView view) { if (path != null && path.trim().length() > 0)
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(path).placeholder(R.drawable.default_user_pic)
                    .error(R.drawable.default_user_pic).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(view);
        else
            Picasso.with(ctx).  load(R.drawable.ic_vector).
            error(R.drawable.ic_vector).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(view);}]
getting view from adapter and setting to layout
layout.addView(madapter.getView(pos, null, null));

Comment: You need to first convert svg file to vector.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem but I found it in my case, with the circleImageView as I changed it from center_crop and tried to adjustViewBounds which is not supported as this requires an unsupported ScaleType and also disabled the fade animations.
and I found the picture that I'm trying to use is going to be large to be cropped and actually it's of no use if you'll have a high resolution picture in a small circle.

Answer (score 0):

Send me more details about problem with. I also share an example that I think glide might be more useful than picasso

```
build.grandle

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'

//MainActivity
final RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.null_image_profile)
            .error(R.drawable.null_image_profile);

    Glide.with(context).load(s.getImage())
            .apply(options)
            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(profileImage);
```